# Swift if sentences issue

Tags: swift, swift2

I am new in Swift and usually work with objective-c and as obj c user it's simple form me to use sentence `if (something) then....` but with a Swift it's a little bit complicated. What I did wrong.

```
let isConnected = QBChat.instance().isConnected

if isConnected // issue Type '() -> Bool' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'
{

}
```

Comment: I guess I have it as obj c method getter. But I go to definition it's also public func isConnected() -> Bool. in obj c it's also a property.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that `isConnected` is not a property, but rather a function or closure. I think you might mean

```
let isConnected = QBChat.instance().isConnected()
```

It's hard to know for sure without seeing how `isConnected` was defined. If the above doesn't work, please show us its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `isConnected` is closure. Try following

```
QBChat.instance().isConnected { isConnected in
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: `isConnected` is of type `() -> Bool`, so the closure doesn't have an argument.